# listbox SelectedIndexChanged with access database

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, listboxitem

Apologies for the messy code.. I have this code below which works perfectly.. it works, populates the listbox with unqiue values.

```
void sumload()
        {
            cn.Open();

            cmd.Connection = cn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT status FROM changes";

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lst_summary2.Items.Add(reader["status"].ToString());
            }
            cn.Close();
        }
```

I want to be be able to select an item from the listbox which will call up another query that populates a second listbox based on that value. I've got it working using a datagrid but cannot seem to get it work with this, any ideas?

```
    private void lst_summary2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string selectedIte = lst_summary2.SelectedItem.ToString();

            cn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = cn;

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM changes WHERE status = '" + selectedIte + "'";

            OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lst_summary3.Items.Add(reader["changetitle"].ToString());
            }
            cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Did you get any error? Try to put a breakpoint on the ExecuteReader and check what is the current value of the selectedIte variable and look if the code enters the loop

Comment: no errors - i've tried inserting messagebox before to output the selected value and after the reader and nothing.. even with breakpoints.. it's as if its not recognising it

Comment: Did you link this event handler to the proper event for the lst_summary2? If it is not called then the event handler is not linked to the event. Check the ListBox property if the SelectedIndexChanged event is linked to this event handler

Comment: @damm Just a sidenote, `SelectedIndexChanged` is trigger by the user and can be triggered programmatically.  You may want to use `SelectionChangeCommitted` which is only triggered when the user changes the value in the `ComboBox`

Comment: @KSdev It is an event for ComboBoxes not for ListBoxes

Comment: @Steve Good call, I need to learn to read better :)

Comment: @KSdev thanks, I'll bear that in mind :)